# How to redirect the user to the log in page in a Facebook App

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, python-2.7, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

I am hosting a Facebook app on Google app engine, I need to make sure the user is logged into facebook before anything.

What I can currently do is display facebook's log in button using fbxml, but I prefer the user would be redirected to Facebook's log in page if he wasn't logged in, then back to my app's main page, this way I can make sure that the user is logged in before doing anything.

I am new to Facebook apps, I read [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) that I can redirect the user to

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL
```

in order to authenticate him. But using GAE's `self.redirect(url)` doesn't work, the page stays the same. I was hoping I could do something like this in my handler:

```
if u'signed_request' in self.request.POST:
        facebook.load_signed_request(self.request.get('signed_request'))
        if not facebook.user_id:
            self.redirect("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"+
                          "client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}"
                          .format(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, EXTERNAL_HREF))
            return
```

but as i said earlier this doesn't work.

Comment: Is redirect not working or is there trouble with Facebook URL?

Comment: Have you checked that the self.redirect method is actually called ?

Comment: The redirect is not working and yes, I am sure it is called

Comment: btw I get a blank screen when the redirect is called

Comment: I just noticed also that I get that error on the JS console when I do the above, it says: `Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming by 'Facebook App' you mean a Canvas App - so something that will live at https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR_NAMESPACE from a user perspective?

If so, you'll need to add the redirect via Javascript using window.top, as your app is loaded in an iframe. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/ and search for 'top', then view the example toward the end of the page.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I mean, I tried adding this: 
`<script>top.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[APP_ID]&redirect_url=http://apps.facebook.com/[APP_NAME]/";</script>`
but then I get an error when I open the page: `An error occurred with [APP_NAME]. Please try again later.`

Comment: Is that error shown in a Facebook window? If so, have you set the domain properly in the app settings?

Comment: Also, I doubt this is a problem, but you should URL encode your redirect url

Comment: it worked! The error was because I wrote `redirect_url` and not the correct `redirect_uri`, so it should be like that: 
`<script>top.location = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[APP_ID]&redirect_uri=http://ap‌​ps.facebook.com/[APP_NAME]/";</script>`

Answer (score 0):

There are also good examples on the Php Sdk that facebook provides. I like the with_js_sdk.php example. It runs seamlessly and is good to follow.
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/